# Simple Database Viewer and Search Tool

Tags: mysql, database, ajax, search, open-source

I've exported all the old orders out of our old store into a mySQL DB.

Anyone know of a simple project or web based app that will let you search all fields with a wildcard?

So if I type in `sha` automatically any results with those letters would popup.

This would be similar to [dbman](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/scripts/dbman/) but with mysql and some ajax.  And preferably free and open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a "fat" client you can download the MySQL GUI tools from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Also look at http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com/

Comment: I think http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com/ was exactly what I was looking for, I'll check it out and get back to you.  Thank you.

Comment: So far MATE looks great.  I'm testing the basic example first, then I'll move on to displaying joins.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyAdmin seems to be the most popular my man.